# JS, Prototype - Перебор элементов DOM

Tags: prototype, dom, javascript

Не получается разобраться с тем как правильно перебирать коллекции.
Селектор $$(".first input") возвращает набор:

```
[<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"id-9" name=​"ids[]​" value=​"9">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"id-23" name=​"ids[]​" value=​"23">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"id-24" name=​"ids[]​" value=​"24">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"id-27" name=​"ids[]​" value=​"27">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"id-1" name=​"ids[]​" value=​"1">​]
```

Делаю проверку отмеченных элементов, если отмечен то помещаю id его в массив:

```
var checkedElemets = [];    
var elements = $$(".first input");

for(var i in elements){
    if(elements[i].getValue('checked') != null){
        checkedElemets.push(elements[i].getValue('checked'));
    }
}
```

Браузер ругается что нет в объекте elements[i] метода getValue. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в моих ошибках.

Причем конструкция elements[i].getValue('checked') где i порядковый номер элемента, в console прекрасно работает:
    > elements[0].getValue('checked') возвращает
    > "9"

Comment: А ты просто elements[i].checked пробовал ?

Comment: Нужно получить value элемента еще и добавить в массив

Comment: Если elements[i] это узел DOM то `elements[i].значение` возвращает аттрибут с именем `значение`.  
Например:  `elements[i].value` возвращяет аттрибут `value`.

Comment: И что вы использовали в результате?

Comment: elements[i].атрибут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, разобрался! Использовал

```
elements[i].атрибут
```